# What approach is best for urgency detection in a statement (Natural Language Processing)?

Tags: nlp

I am working on this problem where i need to understand how urgent it is to respond to a mail. My goal is such that this system should work in any case, meaning the focus must be on the words that show urgency instead of domain specific.

My initial approach was to use a set of words that generally show urgency and then see the similarity of that between the words present in the input statement. It worked very well for simple statements but obviously when it got complicated like "i thought this was urgent , but you can take time" couldn't get classified correctly.

```py
def score(string):
sum = 0
   #calculate average of similarities for words above threshold (0.6)
    for word in string:
        for element in ms:
            score = models.similarity(word,ps.stem(element))
             if pol and score > 0.6:
                 sum+=score
    return sum/len(string)

#my trained MNB model

model = pickle.load(open("MyClassifier-MNB.model","rb"))
#new mail --> "I thought this was urgent, but take your time"
item = account.inbox.filter(is_read=False).order_by('-datetime_received')[0]
score(item.body)

#it is obvious that this will return a good score because i am only checking if the key words are present. What would be a good way to check negation. I also tried using polarity_score from nltk but it couldn't do much.
```

for **"I thought it was urgent but you can take your time"** 
**"Expected Output :**" 
Not Urgent 
**"My Output :**"  
Urgent

Comment: Do you have access to any labelled data? Like for example, 1000 urgent messages and 1000 non-urgent messages? You could train an "urgency" classifier that finds what to look for by itself

Comment: That is the primary problem , i don't have them, i tried to scrape from twitter but it came with other challenges